# clientcontext.executequeryasync gives access denied error in SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, csom

I am having a requirement in which I need to check if user is a member or not of any specific SharePoint group. For this I'm using below code:

```
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {
   var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();
   var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
   currentContext.load(currentUser);

   var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
   currentContext.load(allGroups);
   currentContext.load(allGroups,'Include(users)');

   currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

   function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
       // Success function callback  
       OnComplete(userInGroup);
   }

   function OnFailure(sender, args) {
      OnComplete(false);
   }    
}
```

If current user is site collection administrator then this code is working fine but if user is not site collection administrator then this is not working and giving me below error:

`access denied. you do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource`

This error occurs at `currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);`

Can any one help me what I am doing wrong and why I am getting this error? Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code was not working for me and I was not sure that what was wrong in this code or on the environment. So I just replaced this with below code and I was able to meet my requirement:

**Code**

```
var IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup = function (groupName, OnComplete) {
   var userInGroup = false;
   $().SPServices({
       operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
       userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
       async: false,
       completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            if ($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='" + groupName + "']").length == 1) {
                userInGroup = true;
            }
        }
    });
    OnComplete(userInGroup);
}
```

So basically here I am using [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) and replaced the code with SPServices code.